# How to add +channel and +jobs features to vim

Tags: vim

A vim plugin requires the channel and jobs features but I have tried many suggested ways online and cannot add these two features to vim, even the vim has upgraded to the latest version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  4 2016 10:41:12)
Included patches: 1-764
Compiled by ABC
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2    -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -ldl
```

Does somebody know how to compile these features?

Comment: That is not the newest version. Currently, github is at 7.4.2150 or so. Get the source from there and compile with features=huge should get you channel feature

Comment: But my vim version is already 7.4.764.

Comment: But you need a newer version for the channel feature. Look at the date header, that is from 2013. You should get the recent one from the official repository.

Comment: thanks, would you please give an answer to use github install the latest version +. I am not a git guy.

Comment: the basic usage is explained [here](http://www.vim.org/git.php)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Version 7.4.2152 also says "2013 Aug 10"...

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yeah, sorry for that misinformation

Comment: updating to new version does not solve the issue.

Comment: Actually it should. Can you add what you have done, in the question, so that we can see what isn't going well?

Comment: @DavidZ please show  `:version` output

Comment: The coding area in my question is the `:version` output. What I wanted is to add `+channel` and `+jobs` features.

Answer (score 2):

Got this works:

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git

cd vim/src

sudo make distclean  # if you build Vim before

./configure         --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp \
            --enable-pythoninterp \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-python3interp \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config \
            --enable-perlinterp \
            --enable-luainterp \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope

make

sudo make install
```

Pay close attention to the two paths for Python in that command. You might need to change them if the Python config directory is elsewhere on your machine.